# Javascript array getting updated when not intended

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a discord bot for a small server, and I've encountered a small problem. I have a template variable here:

```
let blankProfile = {
    ID: '',
    name: '',
    maxStrength: 10,
    currentStrength: 10,
    maxHealth: 100,
    currentHealth: 100,
    maxMana: 0,
    currentMana: 0,
    maxDefense: 0,
    currentDefense: 0,
    maxSpeed: 0,
    currentSpeed: 0,
    magic: 0,
    spells: [

    ],
    money: 0,
    position: [1,1],
    items: [

    ],
    isFighting: false,
    wins: [

    ], 
    losses: [

    ]
}
```

of which I tried to change a value. I have a global variable that reads and parses a JSON doc, which I added the template variable to in this function:

```
 function createFighter(userID, fighterName) {

    for(var i = 0; i < playerstats.length; i++) {
        console.log(playerstats[i].ID);
        if(playerstats[i].name == fighterName) {
            return "Please choose a different name."; //To prevent duplicates
        }
        if(playerstats[i].ID == userID) return "You already have a fighter!";
    }   
    blankProfile.name =  fighterName; //this does not "stick" outside of the function
    blankProfile.ID = userID;  //neither does this
    playerstats.push(Object.assign(blankProfile));
    fs.writeFileSync('playerstats.json', JSON.stringify(playerstats, null, 2));
    blankProfile.name = "";
    blankProfile.ID = "";
    console.log(playerstats); //returns desired output, with the correct name and ID


    return "Success!";
}
```

When I tested out this function, it turns out that playerstats updates name and id properly, but when I attempted to `console.log(playerstats)` after calling the function, it returns an array where the name and ID are blank. Why does this happen?

Comment: isn't because you are setting `name` and `ID` to `""` right after `fs.writeFileSync(...` ? Also, where and how are you creating the variable `playerstats` ?

Comment: `Object.assign(blankProfile)`  needs a target. You probably want `Object.assign({}, blankProfile)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You defined `blankProfile`. When you say:

```
blankProfile.name = "";
blankProfile.ID = "";
```

JS is going to go to `blankProfile` and change those values to `''` as assigned here.

To not display that, just do not refer to `blankProfile`:

```
let fakeBlankProfile = blankProfile;
fakeBlankProfile.name = "";
fakeBlankProfile.ID = "";
```

And then if you want to update it:

```
blankProfile = fakeBlankProfile;
```

Comment: In this answer blankprofile and fakeblankprofile point to the same object. Changing one will change the other.

Comment: Nope.  Just try it. `fakeBlankProfile` has the same value of `blankProfile` but doesn't refer to it. (It's just JS!) If you say `fakeBlankProfile.property = value`, JS is going to update the value of `fakeBlankProfile` but will leave `blankProfile` alone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing and modifying properties of an object `blankProfile`. This violates a principle of immutability of data, which if not careful can lead to bugs in your codebase. I would encourage you to create a function (builder, constructor) that returns empty profile (new object each time its called). For example:

```
const getBlankProfile = () => ({
    ID: '',
    name: '',
    maxStrength: 10,
    currentStrength: 10,
    maxHealth: 100,
    currentHealth: 100,
    maxMana: 0,
    currentMana: 0,
    maxDefense: 0,
    currentDefense: 0,
    maxSpeed: 0,
    currentSpeed: 0,
    magic: 0,
    spells: [

    ],
    money: 0,
    position: [1,1],
    items: [

    ],
    isFighting: false,
    wins: [

    ], 
    losses: [

    ]
})
```

Then simply use this function everywhere you want to create new objects.

```
function createFighter(userID, fighterName) {

    for(var i = 0; i < playerstats.length; i++) {
        console.log(playerstats[i].ID);
        if(playerstats[i].name == fighterName) {
            return "Please choose a different name."; //To prevent duplicates
        }
        if(playerstats[i].ID == userID) return "You already have a fighter!";
    }   
    const blankProfile = getBlankProfile();
    blankProfile.name =  fighterName; //this does not "stick" outside of the function
    blankProfile.ID = userID;  //neither does this
    playerstats.push(blankProfile);
    fs.writeFileSync('playerstats.json', JSON.stringify(playerstats, null, 2));
    console.log(playerstats); //returns desired output, with the correct name and ID


    return "Success!";
}
```